# Server responded with 403

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, discord, discord.js

I'm getting this error message when i start my code: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Server responded with 403` how do i fix it?
my code:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (member, guild) => {
 
 
     const leftright = 147; 
     const upkdown = 138; 
     const ksize = 240; 
     const namleftright04 = 310; 
     const namupdown14 = 155; 
     let textsize = 25; 
     
     const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(705,290); 
     const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
     const WelcomeImage = await Canvas.loadImage("./image.png");
     ctx.drawImage(WelcomeImage, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     ctx.font = `${textsize}px px Arial`;
     ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(22, 22, 22, 1)'; 
     ctx.shadowOffsetY = 1; 
     ctx.shadowBlur = 1; 
     ctx.fillStyle = 'WHITE';
     ctx.fillText(member.user.username, namleftright04, namupdown14);
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(leftright, upkdown, ksize/2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
     ctx.closePath();
     ctx.clip();
     const avatarUser = await Canvas.loadImage(
         member.user.avatarURL({ format: 'jpg' })
     );
     ctx.drawImage(
         avatarUser, 
         leftright - 120,
         upkdown - 120,
         ksize, 
         ksize
     )
     const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(
         canvas.toBuffer(),
         'welcome.png'
     );

     const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.id == '870381834624700447');

 
     channel.send(attachment);
});
```

**And I'm getting this error:**

```
(node:11608) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Server responded with 403
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\make\node_modules\canvas\lib\image.js:56:28
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\make\node_modules\simple-get\index.js:89:7
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\make\node_modules\simple-concat\index.js:8:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:519:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:412:35)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:11608) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11608) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
```

Comment: 403 typically means, eventhough the server was able to successfully authenticate a user, this authenticated user is not allowed to access the requested resource (for instance a non-admin is trying to access some values restricted to administrators, or user x is trying to access resources belonging to user y) Assuming, that permission management works correctly on the server, the only way to solve this, is to provide credentials for a user who is allowed to access the requested resources or only request resources which are accessible for the current user.

Comment: did you use `node --trace-warnings ...` as suggested in the error log?

Comment: 403 means "forbidden". You may have an auth issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe take a look at this announcement from the official Discord Developers server.

[image]